# Forecasting when the dependent and independent variables are differenced

Tags: time-series, forecasting, econometrics

Consider the following model for $Y_t$:

$\Delta$log($Y_t)$ = $\beta_0$ + $\beta_1$$\Delta$$log(X_t)$ + $u_t$ where $u_t$ ~ IID Normal(0,$\sigma^2$).

I want a forecast for $Y_{T+1}$. Thus, I need a mathematical formula for $E(Y_{T+1}|\Omega_T)$.

After some algebra we have:

$log(Y_{T+1}) = log(Y_T) + \beta_0 + \beta_1 log(X_{T+1}) - \beta_1 log(X_T) + u_{T+1}$

Taking exponentionals of both sides,

$Y_{T+1} = Y_T e^{\beta_0} {X^{\beta_1}_{T+1}} {X^{-\beta_1}_T} e^{u_{T+1}}$

Then take conditional expectations of both sides with respect to the time $T$ information set:

$E(Y_{T+1}|\Omega_T)$ = $Y_T e^{\beta_0}X_T^{-\beta_1}E({X^{-\beta_1}_{T+1}}e^{u_{T+1}}|\Omega_T)$.

Where do I go from here? What assumptions, if any, do I need to make to chug out a formula for $E(Y_{T+1}|\Omega_T)$.

FYI I am currently using EViews to produce some forecasts. I just want everything to be mathematically sound.

Any suggestions regarding how I should produce a forecast for $Y_{T+1}$?

I should note that I have forecasts for $X_t$, $t >T$.

Thank you.

Christian

Comment: Can you include in your question an elaboration of the "after some algebra" part? I cannot see how you arrived in the expected value for $Y_{T+1}$.

Comment: It looks like you are making a basic mistake: the change in logarithms approximates the _percentage_ change, not the change in levels. I.e. we have  $log(Y_{T+1}) - log(Y_T) = log\frac {Y_{T+1}}{Y_T} = log\left(1+\frac {\Delta Y_{T+1}}{Y_T}\right) \approx \frac {\Delta Y_{T+1}}{Y_T}$

Comment: One more clarification: are the $\beta$ coefficients known a priori, or are they estimated using $(Y,X)$ data up to $T$?

Comment: Yes, they need to be estimated.

Comment: I realise we probably need to assume we know $E(X_{T+1}|\Omega_T)$. This is fine, because my data set includes forecasts for $X_t$, $t>T$ (but obviously not for $Y_t$, $t>T$).

Comment: ...in which case you are done since you are left with $E(e^{u_{T+1}}|\Omega_T) = E(e^{u_{t}}) = e^{\sigma^2/2}$ - the equalities follow from your assumptions on the error term. Then you have the theoretical formula for the expected value of Y, which you will make computuable by using the estimated $\beta$s, and estimated $\sigma$. Alternatively for the $e^{\sigma^2/2}$ term you can use $\frac 1T\sum_{i=1}^{T}e^{\hat u_t}$

Comment: An estimate for $\sigma^2$ is $SSR / (n-k - 1)$. So, to estimate $e^{{\sigma^2} / 2}$, I use $e^{SSR/{n-k-1}}$?

Comment: Don't forget the $\frac 12$

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thank you. Note: this is not the same as ${1/T}\Sigma{e^{u_t}}$.

Comment: Naturally. They are different estimators of the same theoretical quantity, and so bound to produce different estimates.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder which one is better. Any idea?

Comment: In both cases you use the residuals, $\hat u$, squared or not. Use the fact that generally writing, $\hat u = Y- X\hat \beta = X\beta + u - X\hat \beta = u + X(\beta -\hat \beta)$ and try to calculate their properties like unbiasedness, efficiency, consistency.